# FTP List Files (omit path)

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I'm using the CodeIgniter PHP framework. There is a  function to return files as an array: $this->ftp->list_files('my/path/here/');

On my localhost, each item returned includes it's entire path from the root (ie. ./my/path/here/example.jpg).

However, on my live site, it returns only the filename (example.jpg).

How can I get localhost to adapt this behavior by default and ditch the file path? I could write a loop that cleans the items, but I'd rather fix the issue at its root (pun intended) and understand why this discrepancy exists.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To unify / clean up your list into path-free filenames, you can simply apply [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) with [`basename()`](http://php.net/basename) as callback.

CI also seems to provide a [`directory`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/directory_helper.html) helper, which lists local files. It's likely more coherent than your `->ftp` module workaround:

```
 $files = directory_map('./your/path/', 1);
```